# Siemens S7-1200. TRCV_С. Error code: 893A; Event ID 02:253A

Tags: plc, industrial, siemens, s7-1200, tia-portal

Please, help to solve the problem with communication establishment between PC and 1211C (6ES7-211-1BD30-0XB0 Firmware: V 2.0.2). I feel that I've made a stupid mistake somewhere, but can't figure out where exactly it is.
So, I'm using function TRCV_С...

The configuration seems to be okay:

[image]

When i set the CONT=1, the connection establishes without any problems...

[image]

But, when i set EN_R=1, I'm getting "**error 893A**".

[image]

That's what I have in my diagnostic buffer: (DB9 - is a block where the received data is supposed to be written)

[image]

There is an explanation given for "**893A**" in the manuals: **Parameter contains the number of a DB that is not loaded.** In diag. buffer its also written that DB9 is not loaded. But in my case it is loaded! So what should I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that DB were created or edited manually due to which they are miss aligned with FB instances try removing and DB and FB instances and then add again instances of FBs with automatically created DBs and do a offline dowonload